# Have a problem with perl or fedora bash. my source is not recognized unless pre fixed with perl

Tags: perl, fedora

I call the program `myfoo.pl`, my first line is `#!/usr/bin/perl`.
When run from command line `myfoo.pl` I get command not found.
again when run using `perl myfoo.pl` it runs and completes. Not all my perl programs have this problem some run just using (path)/source.pl I ran `head -1 myfoo.pl` and got a print of my first line. no indication of problems.

Comment: Is the Perl binary installed at /usr/bin/perl? Otherwise `where perl` to check

Comment: Can you run the program with `perl myfoo.pl`? You need to be in the same dir as the Perl source file.

Comment: Another possible cause might be lack of executable permission on the file, if you are trying to execute it directly. `./myfoo.pl` to run. `chmod +x myfoo.pl` to add executable permission.

Comment: @TLP It's surely either a permissions issue or (quite sensibly) `PATH` doesn't include`.`.

Comment: @amalloy Yes, I came to the same conclusion. But not enough information until willie answers.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the limited information you gave, I would say you are probably missing permission executable on the file `myfoo.pl`. To which the solution is to do

```
chmod +x myfoo.pl
```

It could also be a path to binary problem, that the perl binary is not located in `/usr/bin/perl`. In which case you need to figure out where it is, with `which perl` or `where perl`.

I suppose it could also be that the file `myfoo.pl` is not in your current directory, which it needs to be. Because of path settings, you also may have to execute it with

```
$ ./myfoo.pl
```

Because `.` is part of your path variable.

It is impossible to say for sure, because you are not answering questions, however. So when you eventually get around to answering questions, we may have more answers.

Comment: Also, make sure the file is a unix file and not a Windows file. The extra CR will cause the interpreter to not be found

Comment: @ikegami Would that not also make the code fail when run with `perl myfoo.pl`?

Comment: @TLP: No. The Perl compiler is quite happy to deal with files with Windows line endings on Unix. It's the shell looking for the compiler that causes the problem - it looks for something called `/usr/bin/perl^M`.